# Is dependent source really a device?

Tags: transistors

Is dependent source really a device like a battery or is just a model as we model transistor with dependent current source?

Comment: A transistor is a device and it's characteristics are dependent on applied voltages, resistor values and temperature. If you stretch your imagination back to the big-bang, every atom is a dependent source.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such physical object as a dependent source, though a great many physical things can be modelled more or less well by a theoretical dependent source.

A power supply can be quite well modelled as a voltage source dependent on the settings of its knobs. Depending on what you want to do with a transistor, a current source dependent on base current or gate voltage can be quite a good model.

Comment: I like to point to the fact that simulation programs contain a BJT model that is - in accordance with physical reality - a voltage-controlled current source (non-ideal, of course, since no ideal sources do exist).

Comment: @LvW BJT = CCCS, MOSFET = VCCS

Comment: @placeholder BJTs are also voltage-controlled. Look up the Ebers-Moll model.

Comment: @placeholder, if you really try to understand what happens inside a BJT, you will see that it is impossible that 3 charged carriers from the base should be able to release 300 charged carriers (other polarity) from the emitter (assuming a beta ratio of 300).

Comment: For a small signal BJT, you can use a VCCS or a CCCS, **depending on which model you choose to use**. It may be convenience, it may be quality of fit, but you choose what model to use to approximate the physical device.

Comment: Neil_UK, for many applications and observable effects (current mirror, emitter degeneration,EARLY effect,..) the use of a CCCS model leads to contradictions or the working principles cannot be explained. Example: Emitter degeneration works only because the BJT is VCCS.

Comment: @AdamHaun The _context_ of the OP is modelling with ideal sources. Matching behaviour is the significant aspect.

Comment: @LvW that comes under 'quality of fit'. This isn't about what model fits best, this is about you can get some aspects of behaviour modelled either as VCCS or CCCS. I can model a car as a 1 tonne concrete weight, if I'm only interested in static road loading! The point of modelling is to use the simplest model that is adequate for the use case.

Comment: Neil_UK, my full agreement. And there is only one model that "fits best" (that means: can explain and verify ALL observable effects): The transconductance model. That is the reason this model is used in all circuit simulation programs.

Comment: @LvW There is only one model that fits best, and that's the physical transistor. **All** other models have deviations from what the transistor actually does, which is why choice of an *adequate for purpose* model is important. I am sure that 95%+ of 'back of envelope' transistor designs in the world use the hFE+CCCS model. Knowing the demographic that this forum services, I think that would rise to 99%+. When I was a microwave designer doing single transistor amplifiers, I used gm for gain, and hFE for DC bias, and so did the rest of the lab.

Comment: Yes - everybody uses hfe because it determines the base current which is needed for calculation of the DC bias resistors. So what? Does this imply that Ib would control  Ic? Of course, not. The relation Ib=Ic/hfe is used very often, but such an equation has no meaning as far as cause and result are concerned. As you have mentioned the "physical transistor": Do you agree that the collector current of the "physical transistor" is controlled solely by Vbe (Shockleys equation)?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you ever used a lab power supply, you actually used a dependent source. The output voltage of the power supply depends on the voltage (or current) that you set with the front panel knobs.

Comment: This is wrong. A dependent voltage source is a source whose output depends on another electrical quantity in the circuit. The output of the lab PS is not a function of the powered circuit (usually). The variation of the voltage due to the operator turning the knob could be modeled as a time-varying **independent** source.

Comment: I don't agree. The output of the lab PS is dependent of the voltage on the voltage divider who is the reference for the regulator. The output voltage is dependent on the voltage on a voltage divider. That is exactly the definition of a dependent voltage source.

Comment: That's not an useful answer with respect to the question, IMO. According to the argument you make, almost everything could be a dependent source: every active component can be modeled by a subcircuit containing a dependent source (transistors, opamps, etc.). Ok, if you consider the *actual PS circuit* as part of the whole circuit, you are right, but the OP is looking for a real-world equivalent of a dependent source, which in circuit theory is a 4-terminal network, where the electrical quantity at the input controls the electrical quantity at the output.

Comment: The lab PS actual circuit ***contains independent sources***, but taken as a whole, it is not. In your argument, you are separating the voltage setting circuit from the output stages of the PS and say that the wires that connect them are the input. Correct, but misleading, since it is not the PS as a whole which is a dependent source, it's the output stage that is a dependent source (in fact it is essentially an amplifier, at least in the linear case).

Answer (score 0):

Of course, for a reasonable range of conditions a BJT is a dependent source, with the collector current a (more or less) constant multiple of the base current.

Answer (score 0):

In SPICE modelling you use dependant sources to model ideal circuits, these can be anything from an ideal transistor as mentioned by others, to whole blocks that might eventually be implemented with op-amps etc.  In fact you can also use dependant sources to model the non-idealities of a "real" circuit/device to gain insight, to act as a placeholder until you implement the final design or any number of reasons.

Given the performance levels of modern op-amps, one might be able to come close to emulating an ideal dependant source (but never fully).  This would be very ironic of course and some what a exercise in futility. So it doesn't really matter if a ideal source has a real world analog, all that matters is *how* you use them.